# Grouping adjacent elements by a sibling delimiter element

Tags: c#, linq

A general problem I run into a lot when parsing "human-readable" data into some more convenient data structure is the following:

Suppose I have a list of sibling elements:

```
var input = new[] {"moo", "*", "foo", "bar", "baz", "*", "roo", 
                   "moo", "*", "*", "hoot", "*", "boot"};
```

I know that the `*` is a delimiter that groups all adjacent elements until the next delimiter.  So the "more convenient" data structure associated with this input is:

```
var expectedOutput = new List<List<string>>
  {
    new List<string> {"moo"},
    new List<string> {"*", "foo", "bar", "baz"},
    new List<string> {"*", "roo", "moo"},
    new List<string> {"*"},
    new List<string> {"*", "hoot"},
    new List<string> {"*", "boot"}
  };
```

In the past, I've written my parser as an extension method, with similar syntax to LINQ:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupByDelimiter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, T delimiter)
{
    var currentList = new List<T>();
    foreach (T item in input)
    {
        if (!item.Equals(delimiter))
        {
            currentList.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            yield return currentList;
            currentList = new List<T> {item};
        }
    }

    // return the last list
    yield return currentList;
}
```

This is works just fine, but I was wondering **if this method `GroupByDelimiter` could be re-written using existing LINQ extension methods**. Better yet, is there some LINQ method that I do not know about that already does this?

Comment: It is probably possible to express this using existing LINQ operations - `Aggregate` would be my first choice - but you would not gain much, just an indigestible mess. Your solution is absolutely okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a quirky way using conditon as grouping delimiter.

```
var input = new[] {"moo", "*", "foo", "bar", "baz", "*", "roo", 
                   "moo", "*", "*", "hoot", "*", "boot"};
    int index = 0;
    var output = input.Select( x => new
                 {
                   Item=x, 
                   GroupCondition = x =="*" ? ++index:index     // Introduce GroupCondition, Increase it if delimiter is found      
                 })
          .GroupBy((x)=>x.GroupCondition)                      // Group by GroupCondition
          .Select( x => x.Select( y => y.Item));                // Get rid of GroupCondition
```

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/1urN8N)

Demo output

```
moo
* foo bar baz
* roo moo
*
* hoot
* boot
```